# Apex: Where is a good/recommended place to store custom error messages?

Tags: error-messages, bestpractice, customlabel

In order to avoid creating duplicate string literals (the error messages) in both the class that would, for example, throw an exception and its corresponding test class, where is a good/recommended place to store these strings, Custom metadata types, custom labels, another class?(I only named those places where to store strings to ilustrate what I mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Custom Label to store strings of this nature. This not only centralizes these strings, but also provides a forward path for translation into multiple languages in the future. They're also easy to access in places other than Apex, such as Visualforce pages, Lightning Components, etc.